# Why would I use VARCHAR over TEXT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I noticed that in MySQL, both VARCHAR and TEXT offer variable-sized data. Well, VARCHAR is a bit more efficient in data storage, but still, TEXT MEDIUMTEXT and LONGTEXT offer a lot more potential. So, what are the real uses of VARCHAR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you should read the [**10.4. String Types**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-types.html) section of the MySQL's manual : it'll give you all the informations you are looking for :

- [10.4.1. The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html)
- [10.4.3. The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html)

A couple of important differences :

- Difference in the amount of text those can contain :

  - varchar have a quite small size limit ; with the newest versions of MySQL, it's 64 KB, for the total of all varchar columns of a row -- which is not that much.
  - TEXT have virtually no limit, as they can contain something like 2^32 bytes.
- There are differences in indexing and sorting, if I'm not mistake ; quoting [the page about TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html) :

  - About sorting : "*Only the first [`max_sort_length`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sort_length) bytes of the column are used when sorting.*"
  - And, about performances : "*Instances of BLOB or TEXT columns in the result of a query that is processed using a temporary table causes the server to use a table on disk rather than in memory*"

Considering these informations, if you are sure that your strings will not be too long, and that you'll always be able to store them in a varchar, I would use a varchar.